# What is the name of the occupation of the person in charge of lighting effects on stage?

Tags: single-word-requests, cinema

On a drama or stage show, there's always a person takes care of the lighting effects, but I don't know how to express that occupation. Does anyone know what it's called?

Comment: 'Lighting technician' or 'lighting tech' works for a 'lighting designer' or 'master electrician'. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighting_technician).

Comment: Is there an shorter noun of 'Lighting technician'? Like 'lighting guy' , 'lightman' or something else ?

Comment: Well  'leccy' is an abbreviation for electrician, but the word 'lighty' is already used as urban or slang to describe someone of a dark-skinned race whose skin is lighter than usual.

Answer (score 4):

The term "lighting technician" would probably be apt for a theatre or stage show.

> People who work on stage lighting are commonly referred to as lighting
>   technicians.

[Stage lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stage_lighting)

You asked for a shorter of more informal term, there is also the term gaffer.

Gaffer

> A gaffer in the motion picture industry and on a television crew is
>   the head electrician, responsible for the execution (and sometimes the
>   design) of the lighting plan for a production.

[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaffer_(filmmaking))

However the definition of gaffer seems to always be given as a person on a movie or television set.

Also interesting:

> In video, television, and film productions, lighting technicians work
>   under the direction of the gaffer or chief lighting technician who
>   takes their direction from the cinematographer.

[Lighting technician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighting_technician)

Also, note that "gaffer" isn't that common outside its respective industry. So if you're going to use it for a casual/everyday audience/readership, they probably won't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Yeah, gaffer is really a casual word for lighting tech. I'm not going to use it. I got another word calls 'lampy'. It looks pretty good and intuitive. Is this word has any unfriendly meanings?

Comment: @naive232 No unfriendly meanings that I know of, it's just that I've never heard of the word. Are you writing a novel or something?

Comment: I found the 'lampy' at wiki page：https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighting_technician

Comment: @naive231 Nice work. I'd never heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've always known them as Lampies (Lampie singular). Here's an [example in use](https://www.onstagelighting.co.uk/learn-stage-lighting/stage-lighting-terms-guide-lampie-slang/):

> On Stage Lighting presents an essential guide to stage lighting jargon and UK **lampie** slang for anyone who needs to understand what these weirdos are talking about or needs to blag it as a member the LX department.

Comment: Is this word actually in use, though? If you could add a definition, it would be wonderful; the next best thing would probably be adding a few example sentences and giving us some context as to where and when it was used, and possibly whether it's an 'insider term'.

Comment: I recall hearing that term several times about 40 years ago.  I think it was when I was hanging with some theatre folks.